# How to show toolbar window when clicking on statusbar in an OSX app?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am working on an OSX app which is mainly a toolbar app. This app also prowides a status bar. This status bar is mainly to display some data, and has no menu.

Now I want to add the possibility that, when the status bar is clicked, the toolbar window gets to the front. As far as I found out, this is done like:

```
NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

What I haven't found yet is how I get my statusbar item to perform that. I created a function, and tried it with statusitem.perform, but that doesn't work.

Thanks,
Jack